# Как сделать pop-up c полными данными из sql на клике по строке таблицы?

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

Здравствуйте! У меня есть база сотрудников, я вывел короткое описание каждого на сайт в виде таблицы и хотел сделать, чтобы при клике на строку появлялось окошко *с полной информацией по сотруднику* (с изображениями, но они не хранятся в базе, может на них можно сделать ссылки?)

Edit:

*Можно как-нибудь использовать связь с sql? Таким образом чтобы алгоритм сравнивал какой-нибудь уникальный атрибут(например № Удостоверения) из строки в таблице с данными из sql и выводил pop-up с данными о сотруднике с таким атрибутом. Не вписывая данные о каждом сотруднике вручную.*

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Список сотрудников</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class = "header">
<img src = "img/header.png"></img>
</div>

<div class = "container-fluid">
<?php

echo "<table class = 'table table-striped'>";
echo "<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>№</th>
        <th>ФИО</th>
        <th>Имя транслитом</th>
        <th>Дата рождения</th>
        <th>Должность</th>
        <th>Дата приёма на работу</th>
        <th>№ удостоверения</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
function __construct($it) { 
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
}

function current() {
    return "<td style='width:14%;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
}

function beginChildren() { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
} 

function endChildren() { 
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
} 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "test";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", 
$username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT number, fullname, engname,birthdaydate, 
position, recruitmentDate,id FROM employees"); 
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as 
$k=>$v) { 
    echo $v;
}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
</div>
<div class = "footer">
<img src = "img/footer.jpg"></img>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script     
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно в строке таблицы выводить data-аттрибутами инфу о конкретном работнике, и при клике на строку - брать данные из этих аттрибутов.

```
<tr data-name="Сергей" data-post="Охранник" class="show-info">
    <td>...</td>
<tr>
```

А потом, при клике на tr.show-info показывать окошко с инфой. Можно самому написать, а можно плагин взять какого-то модального окна.

Comment: Можно ли сделать это используя sql запросы? Может есть возможность сравнивания ячеек в строке с ячейками в базе данных?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, наверно.

```
 <script>
    function showMore() {
    var n = $('.personal_container').lenght; //считает кол-во элементов, равно числу контейнеров с персонами
    for(h=0;h<=n;h++){ // циклируем
    $('#'+h).on('click', function(){
    $('.person_more_'+h).show(); //при клике на внешний контейнер - показываем внутрений
    });
    };
    };
    </script>
    <?
    $persons = ...;// тут массив с кучей пользователей и их данными
    $x = count($persons); // считаем кол-во пользователей
    for($i=0;$i<=$x;$i++){ // вводим в цикл
    ?>
    <div class="personal_container" onClick="showMore()" id="<?=$i?>"> // для каждого создаем отдельный контейнер с уникальным id
    <div class="person_visiable"> // сюда выводим то, где будет лежать заранее видимая инфа
    <span> Краткая инфо о сотруднике </span>
    <div class="person_more_<?=$i?>"> // сюда выводим то, что под катом
    <span> много инфы о сотруднике </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать это используя sql запросы? Может есть возможность сравнивания ячеек в строке с ячейками в базе данных?

Comment: Ну Вы из мускуля загрузите данные в $persons, а там уже циклом из массива берите.   Или я как-то не так понял Ваш вопрос)

Comment: в формате json вводить данные в $persons?

Comment: можно в формате json, можно хоть xml засовывать - исключительно в том формате, в котором Вам их потом удобнее выводить)

Comment: Я попытался закинуть таблицу в массив:
    $persons = $dbh->query("select * from employees");
Ничего не происходит, видимо я что-то делаю не так

Comment: а как Вы её потом выводите?

Comment: Я не знаю, как вывести эту информацию в те блоки, которые Вы создали.

Comment: @DamirBadilov учите javascript. php,sql этим способом вы только выведите инфу на страницу, а при клике показывать - за это отвечает javascript.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь